# Android Screenshot With A Generic Status Bar

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm about to publish my app on the app store and I want to take screenshots of my app without all the information in my status bar like carrier and debug mode and such.

I know that for Marshmallow, there is the System UI Tuner that exists but I failed to find an equivalent for Lollipop..

Does any of you has any clue to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Clean Status Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emmaguy.cleanstatusbar) could be what you're looking for. It overlays a blank status bar on your device with a configurable choice of icons.

Answer (score 1):

I just published an open source app [*QuickDemo*](https://github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/QuickDemo), for configuring and accessing the Android System UI demo mode. Instead of overlaying the original status bar, it modifies its content. It also comes with a Nougat quick settings tile, for fast access from any screen.